# How to efficiently stream video over HTTP directly from SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, video-streaming, scalability

I'm trying to implement a video-streaming service. I use ASP.NET Web API, and as I've searched, PushStreamContent is exactly what I want, and it works very fine, sending HTTP response 206 (partial content) to the client, keeping the connection alive and pushing (writing) streams of bytes to the output.

However, I can't scale. Because I can't retrieve partial binary data from database. For example consider that I have a 300MB video in my SQL Server table (varbinary field) and I use Entity Framework to get the record, and then push it to the client using PushStreamContent.

However, this hugely impacts RAM. And for each **seeking** action that client does, the RAM uses another extra 600MB of space. Look at it in action:

1) First request for video
[image]

2) Second request (seeking to the middle of the video)
[image]

3) Third request (seeking into the last quarter of the video)
[image]

This can not be scaled at all. 10 users watching this movie, and our server is down.

What should I do? How can I stream video directly from SQL Server table without loading the entire video into RAM with Entity Framework and then pushing it to client via `PushStreamContent`?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx) function with [VARBINARY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188362.aspx) fields, to return portions of your data.  But I suspect you'd prefer a solution that doesn't require jumping from one chunk to the next.

You may also want to review this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777840/how-do-i-select-just-a-portion-of-huge-binary-file-from-sql-server-2008).